# Excel formula using more if

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula

I have a problem with my nested if condition as an Excel formula. I know it would be easier by using VBA, but I have to do it this way.

This is my formula, but it returns FALSE:
=IF(D:D="SUPER";IF(AND(AA:AA="0";AA:AA="1");"V";IF(AA:AA="3";"R";"O")))

The D:D column has 3 filters, I have to apply the same formula with each filter.
The AA:AA column has the following conditions:
- if 0 and 1 -> V
- if 3 -> R
- if anything else -> O

I don't know why it doesn't work, but I would appreciate any advice!
[This will return R, because there is 3 in there](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NhvAU.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/46DuA.png)

Comment: Well, at first glance you want the AND() to be true when a cell in the range AA:AA is both 0 and 1 ? Did you possibly mean OR() so a "V"is entered for values of 0 or 1 ?

Comment: @SolarMike Looks like you wrote the same thing as I did minute earlier, if you want to write it as an answer, I'll erase mine

Comment: @M.Douda no, I was 15 seconds in front of you, and it is not an issue : you have done a good job.

Comment: @Jeeped not this time, but I was trying to drive the OP to apply OR()  themselves, but that may not be the only issue based on the OP's comments...

Comment: I deleted my answer as there seems to be a different issue, it would be helpful if you included some sample data so we can properly explain what exactly is wrong.

Comment: This question needs to show data and expected results - please add it to the question - do not add it in comments.

Comment: @M.Douda put it back and I'll vote it up anyway - I think it is still part of the issue - as based on how the explanation in the 3rd para is phrased.

Comment: @Anca Vulc Sorry but your edit doesn't help at all, can you please attach a picture of the data, your current results and expected results ? If the data is confidential please create an example data that you can share.

Comment: I edited it. So I want for Super, in Column D, for example, to see if in column AA if there are only 0 and 1, to return V, if there if any 3 in there, to return R, and if there if for any Super - 'something', to return O

Comment: @M.Douda I attached a picture now

Comment: @Anca Vulc Ok, thank you, as I thought the issue is different, can you unmerge the cells or is it absolutely vital ?

Comment: Is the formula supposed to work for 2 rows under each other or is it variable ?

Comment: The formula will make the statement just one time, this is why I merged the cells, I don't want to say it for each row.

Comment: Maybe OP wants to know if cells adjacent to "Super" contain both a value of 0 and a value of 1 (disregarding rows)?

Comment: Is this a normal formula or an array formula?

Comment: @JvdV I don't exactly understand what you mean by that. On the column where Super is, it is one of 3 filters that can be applied on the column. For each of them, I have to calculate the same thing, and put the result somewhere, that doesn't matter(I will have 3 cells with results).

Comment: @Dominique it s a normal formula I guess, because I just need one cell for the result

Comment: @AncaVulc Ok I understand what's going on now. This will definitely have to be an array formula (formula intered with Ctrl + Space + Enter), I'll try to recreate the issue.

Comment: I posted another picture in my post, with how I logically thought it

Comment: Your second image contradicts the first. Nested IF statements 'short-circuit'; that is to say that once one is true, the rest are abandoned. Your first image has both AND(SUPER/0, SUPER/1) as well as SUPER/3 and you stated the result should be R. The logic in your second image states that AND(SUPER/0, SUPER/1) is resolved first and since that is true the result should be V.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is more a matter of prioritizing logic flow. It seems that at least a single occurrence of SUPER with 3 supersedes the rest. The next priority would be SUPER with 0 and SUPER with 1 (both must occur). If none of those apply, default to O.

```
=if(countifs(d:d, "super", aa:aa, 3), "R", if(not(and(countifs(d:d, "super", aa:aa, 0), countifs(d:d, "super", aa:aa, 1))), "O", "V"))
'with semi-colons
 =if(countifs(d:d; "super"; aa:aa; 3); "R"; if(not(and(countifs(d:d; "super"; aa:aa; 0); countifs(d:d; "super"; aa:aa; 1))); "O"; "V"))
```

Comment: It only works for the V results, but it won't show the O

Comment: I missed a bunch of a's. All of my AA:AA references were A:A. Fixed above.

Comment: I already changed that when I applied my formula, I don't think it's that

Comment: I get it now, it is a matter of priorities, first it should be for 3, then anything else and then for 0 and 1. Can you help me with changing that?

Answer (score 0):

```
=IF(COUNTIFS(D:D;"super";AA:AA;3)<>0;"R";IF(COUNTIFS(D:D;"super";AA:AA;1)*COUNTIFS(D:D;"super";AA:AA;0)=0;"O";"V"))
```

The order of the criteria was wrong, also you generally can't refer to entire columns in the way you did. This formula first checks whether there's any cell with the value 3. Then if there isn't it multiplies the count of 1s and 0s to check whether there are both numbers present.

Comment: It doesn't work after I change it with my values, says the syntax if wrong. The 0,1,3 values are strings, I don't if it s that